# Moving multiple gigabytes between two Windows PCs daily without being on the same network

Tags: windows, networking, ftp, file-transfer

I need to move multiple gigabytes (15-100GB per week) of video footage between two Windows machines that are not on the same network.

Both networks have daily changing IP addresses (forced restart via ISP) which makes my current setup (FTP) a bit annoying.

My question is, is there another option that I haven't discovered yet to move multiple gigabytes of data between two PC's without relying on shipping thumb drives or uploading to a cloud service?

Comment: One easy way would be to use Zerotier. You can add both machines to a virtual zerotier network for free and then just send data between the 2 computers as if they were on the same local network.

Comment: I used to use bitorrent sync (now resilio sync) for it, its no longer free though. Do the two PCs have 'public' IPs at least? And do your transfers need to be resilient to these restarts?

Comment: You could buy a static IP address from your ISP for the target machine, and you'll not need to change your current setup at all.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The PC's do have a public IP address and they don't need to be resilient as the file transfers are usually done within the hour.

Comment: @harrymc Sadly my current ISP only offers static IP addresses in much more expensive business plans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to use your current setup (with `ftp` transfers) and set on target server some Dynamic DNS service. Then set the ftp client to use the new selected hostname and Dynamic DNS service will take care of refresh the DNS records when ISP change it.

Comment: The technical term for the OP to look for is "Dynamic DNS service"

Comment: @Yorik, thank you, will update my answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the info! I looked through some dynamic DNS providers and found out that most of them offer IP updates via API calls, which my router appears to support, so this is likely to be the best permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are P2P file synchronization tools for dynamic network environments that allow folder synchronization using either a direct connection or relaying in case of firewall\NAT

The most notable examples are proprietary Resilio Sync (formerly BitTorrent Sync) and open-source Syncthing.

Both are easy to use but Syncthing has a steeper learning curve

https://www.resilio.com/

https://syncthing.net/

P.S. I would not advise using Zerotier for file transfer purposes in a case when a direct connection could not be established, as there are only 4 relay servers managed by Zerotier Inc. which simply do not provide enough bandwidth.